# Sprite appears on key press

Tags: python

What I want the code to do is that, when I press the Up arrow key, it should blit a sprite onto the screen, but it's not. Any ideas why?

(No help needed)

```
while 1:
    event = pygame.event.poll()
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        pygame.quit()
        sys.exit(0)
    elif event.type == pygame.K_a:
        screen.blit(image05,(75,50))
        pygame.display.flip()

while True:
    event = pygame.event.poll()
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
    pygame.quit()
    sys.exit(0)
```

Answer (score 4):

I hope you'll forgive me for being blunt about this first part but your while loops are evidence of some major copy/paste ignorance in the realm of flow-control.  Those loops are also exactly the problem, which is why I mention them at all.

1. You're going to want *just one* while loop to poll for input that is not equal to the quit event.
2. Then, *within* that loop you're going to want to define your input cases (if statements)
3. Dispatch the input to your own code to respond or act however you choose --in this case, moving the sprite on that up arrow key.
4. Always allow for the loop to close in some way.

***Short answer:*** It's not working because you're only allowing the program to quit before it ever responds to another input event.

And please read an article about while, for, foreach, do/until.  I'll find one and update this answer with a link to it.

1. Here's python's documentation about [loop usage and syntax](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Loops)
2. Here's [control flow from the wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_flow) which will absolutely ease your journey.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed. Don't put code after an infinite loop or a sys.exit() statement. The correct way to do this is:

```
while 1:
    event = pygame.event.wait() #use wait to prevent busy loop
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
       pygame.quit()
       sys.exit(0)
    elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN && event.key == pygame.K_a:
         screen.blit(draw_me1,(25,25))
    pygame.display.flip()
```

This will trigger on the "a" key, not the up arrow. To make it trigger on the up arrow key, use a different key constant.